# blockchain wallet address expire time for transaction verification

Tags: payment-gateway, verification, bitcoin, blockchain

I want to have a bitcoin gateway on my site.
I downloaded blockchain api source it seems to work well.

blockchain api source:

#### https://github.com/blockchain/receive_payment_php_demo

when I click on that payment button's image , it creates an wallet address for me on blockchain.
And everything is fine .
But my question is , how long my user can pay btc into that wallet address and what is its expire time?

If my user pay btc to that wallet address but that address was not valid anymore, what will be happened on my users money.

Answer (score 1):

Addresses will never expire.  As long as you have the private key you can use it forever.  And if you lost your key and a user sent BTC there, it will stay there but you can never claim it anymore. I know this question is old but do you still need help with you API?